# Error with curdir (ntpath) python

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I have been working with the ntpath, curdir feature of python but it is not working! Note that if I have a direct path to the data files, no error occurs. I need to be using relative paths with the project and cannot be hard coding my files in the project.

Here's my error:

```
Parent suite setup failed:
File not found error :.\DataSetFiles\uOpen Data Extract updated - CID94746.xlsx doesnot exist
```

At script start up, here's what happens:

**__init__.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    ../Generic_Configurations/Import_File.robot
```

**Import_File.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Variables    ../Generic_Configurations/ConfigurationsFile.py
```

**ConfigurationsFile.py**

```
from ntpath import curdir

DataExtractFile = curdir + '\\DataSetFiles\\uOpen Data Extract updated - CID94746.xlsx'
DataSheetFile = curdir + '\\DataSetFiles\\DataSheet.xlsx'
```

I'm scripting robot framework with the Eclipse IDE.

Any comments/suggestions appreciated!

Comment: `\uOpen`. Is the `u` intentional?

Comment: Is that really the actual error message? It seems to have a typo, which is a bit unusual for error messages.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the file exists _relative to the current directory_, which may not be the same as the directory that the test is in? What do you get if you type `dir` at the same prompt where you're trying to run your tests? Does it list the file? Can you include in your question exactly how the file appears from the `dir` command?

Comment: What was your intent using `curdir` from `ntpath`? If you were planning for it to automatically put the cwd,  that won't happen - it's just a string constant, equal to `.` in windows and posix. If that wasn't the case (e.g. you are aware of that), and the filenames are correct, the problem might be what is the current working directory when you execute the robot script - it must be the parent directory of "DataSetFiles".

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse project files were located in the wrong 'relative' location. Once I was able to format the folders properly, the issue got resolved. Thanks